# What is the most efficient way to extract local minima from a DataFrame and then output them to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe of the following format:

```
Location |  Y   | X
--------------------
A1       | -10  | 1
A1       | -20  | 2
A1       | -10  | 3
A1       | -25  | 4
A2       | -10  | 1
A2       | -20  | 2
A2       | -10  | 3
A2       | -25  | 4
```

Let's for simplicity sake assume that for A1 and A2, -20 and -25 are the local minima. Let's assume there are lots of locations (say around 1000), and assume that for each location there are lots of data points (say also around 1000).

I want to get this table:

```
Location | min for Y
--------------------
A1       | -20
A1       | -25
A2       | -20
A2       | -25
```

My current algorithm takes too long. Briefly, in pseudo python code:

```
minima_list = []
loc_list = []
for location in locations:
    # Find all minima, transform to temp_list, and append to long list
    temp_list = find_minima
    minima_list += temp_list
    loc_list += [location for item in temp_list]
res = pd.DataFrame({'min': Series(minima_list), 'loc': Series(loc_list)
```

This approach is approach is long due to the multiple, it's still slightly faster faster than outputting the individual outputs to a dataframe and then concatenating them all - my guess is because of the overhead associated with setting up dataframes and then concatenating them.

But this approach still takes too long. On just 500,000 total data points, it takes 5-6 seconds. Therefore, I am wondering if there is an even more elegant way that is also more efficient.

The transform method seems to work when the input length =  output length. But in this case the output DF will be a subset of the input table. The output is also different then the input.

I am thinking of trying out np.arrays. My intuition is that if I can vectorize the operation it will be faster. But I am also not sure how. So I thought I would ask the community for a much more elegant and performant approach than my loopy-loo approach before I go on a 2 hour drive back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [scipy.signal.argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) method:

```
In [198]: from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

In [199]: df
Out[199]:
  Location   Y  X
0       A1 -10  1
1       A1 -20  2
2       A1 -10  3
3       A1 -25  4
4       A2 -10  1
5       A2 -20  2
6       A2 -10  3
7       A2 -25  4

In [200]: df.loc[argrelextrema(df.Y.values, np.less)]
Out[200]:
  Location   Y  X
1       A1 -20  2
3       A1 -25  4
5       A2 -20  2
```

PS IMO you can't say whether the last point is a local minima unless we know the next point - for example if in next (virtual) row you would have `-30` ...

Comment: I think I actually tried this. The problem with this approach is that this method just looks at all local extrema.In theory, a local extrema could be identified at boundadry cases where the df transitions from one location to another. I want to avoid this scenario. I would like local extrema to be identified by location. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it remains the fastest answer. This answer will produce edge case artifacts. If one knows this, one can somehow remove those in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using pandas, for instance:

```
# Group df by 'Location'
location_groups = df.groupby(['Location'])

# Loop location_groups
for location, location_group in location_groups:

    # Sort this location group ascending by 'Y', get the first 2 rows on top
    minimas = location_group.sort_values(by='Y').head(2)

    # Append minimas to df2
    df2.append(minimas, ignore_index=True)
```